# Is a section of the sphere trapped by two great circles homeomorphic to a disc?

Tags: algebraic-topology

By this I mean if you take a lune of a closed ball, then intersect it with the boundary (i.e. the $2$-sphere), you get the section of the sphere trapped by two great circles.

Is this shape homeomorphic to a closed disc?

Intuitively (perhaps wrongly), I think you can flatten the area into a closed disc (or at least something homeomorphic to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean a single connected component? If so, then it's homeomorphic to an open disk (unless you mean to include the boundary in which case the closed disk). Unless I misunderstand your question, the homeomorphism is just to (i) project the section onto a plane, (ii) define coordinates on the plane and with origin at the center of the image of the section, and (iii) define a continuous map that projects the section radially outward from the center of the section onto the radius of a disk (push the section out).

Comment: You've indeed understood the question correctly, and yes, I did mean with the boundary. That was a surprisingly easy homeomorphism, thank you!